# Create WCF addressing headers for reply message

Tags: wcf, ws-addressing

I have a generic service with this interface

```
[OeprationContract(Action="*", ReplyAction="*")]
Message ProcessMessage(Message message);
```

In the implementation, I have to set up the headers of the reply message.
Is there a way to create the right addressing headers from the input message or do I have to set everything manually (i.e. copy In.replyTo to out.To, copy In.messageId to out.MessageId, ...)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do it manually; when you declare an operation taking an returning a `Message` object you're basically telling WCF that you want total control over the message, so no correlation between request and reply will be done for you.